# obter entidades HTML originais com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso de todas as entidades HTML originais de um parágrafo, principalmente os acentos, os métodos que conheço recuperam somente algumas entidades, conforme o exemplo abaixo onde ">" é codificado corretamente mas o "ç" não.

É importante que o código possa diferenciar acentos gerados ou não por entidades (como em `&ccedil;ã`) pois o conteúdo vem de uma fonte externa e pode vir sem um padrão definido

```js
alert(document.querySelector('p').innerHTML);
```

```html
<p>situa&ccedil;ão &gt; ativo</p>
```

---

Notas: conforme a resposta aceita do @mgibsonbr não é possível, a solução adotada foi utilizar a função [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.savehtml.php), ela interpreta as entidades da mesma maneira que o navegador, de forma que os dados ficam iguais no servidor e no cliente.

Comment: Essa é uma ótima pergunta! Eu não sei em que momento do *parsing* as entidades HTML são resolvidas, nem se isso é preservado em algum lugar ou descartado. Verificando os filhos do `p`, vejo que há apenas um nó `Text`, cujo `data` (de `CharacterData`) é a string com todas as suas entidades resolvidas (inclusive o `>`). Sendo assim, me parece que a informação que quer não existe mais após a página ser carregada, de modo que você precisaria obter esse conteúdo dessa fonte externa (seja no lado servidor, ou talvez via ajax se aplicável) e tratá-lo antes do *browser* interpretar seu HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As entidades HTML originais não são preservadas quando o *markup* do documento é interpretado (*parsed*) pelo *browser*, de modo que não estão disponíveis para você consultá-las via JavaScript ou de qualquer outra maneira. Segundo a especificação, durante a etapa de [*tokenization*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization) (leitura do texto "cru" e produção de "peçados" - ou *tokens* - para subsequente análise) as entidades HTML (aqui chamadas de *Character Reference*) produzem um único caractere [quando consumidas](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#consume-a-character-reference):

> ## 8.2.4.69 Tokenizing character references
>
> ...
>
> O comportamento depende da identidade do próximo caractere (aquele imediatamente depois do U+0026 AMPERSAND), da seguinte forma:
>
> ### ...
>
> ### "#" (U+0023)
>
> Consuma o U+0023 NUMBER SIGN.
>
> ...
>
> Consuma todos os caracteres que casam o intervalo de caracteres listados acima (dígitos hexadecimais ASCII ou dígitos ASCII).
>
> ...
>
> Caso contrário, se o próximo caractere é um U+003B SEMICOLON, consuma-o também. Se não for, é um erro de *parsing*.
>
> ...
>
> Caso contrário, **retorne um token de caractere para o caractere Unicode cujo ponto de código é aquele número**.
>
> ### Qualquer outra coisa
>
> Consuma o máximo número de caracteres possíveis, desde que os caracteres consumidos casem com um dos identificadores na primeira coluna da tabela de [referência de caracteres nomeados](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) (diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas).
>
> ...
>
> **Retorne um ou dois tokens de caracteres para o(s) caractere(s) correspondente(s) ao nome do caractere na referência** (dado pela segunda coluna da tabela de [referência de caracteres nomeados](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references)).

(tradução livre, ênfase minha)

Ou seja, após o documento HTML ter sido *"parseado"* e o HTML resultante formado (bem como sua representação no DOM) a informação sobre as entidades HTML utilizadas não estão mais lá - foram substituídas pelos seus caracteres correspondentes. O fato do `innerHTML` (e `outerHTML`) devolverem o texto com o `&gt;` escapado se deve ao fato dele "reescapá-lo" pra você, independentemente da forma como ele estava originalmente no *markup*:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('p').innerHTML);
```

```html
<p>situa&ccedil;ão > ativo</p>
```

Portanto, se você realmente precisa dessa informação terá de obtê-la antes do texto do documento chegar ao *browser* como HTML: no lado servidor, por exemplo, ou - se estiver obtendo o texto via Ajax - analisando o texto antes de criar elementos com ele. Infelizmente isso implica em analisar o texto do HTML você mesmo, o que não é nada trivial... *Talvez* alguma biblioteca de *parsing* seja capaz de ao mesmo tempo tratar das entidades (de preferência reconhecendo todas que compõem a especificação) e preservar o conteúdo original das mesmas, mas de cabeça não conheço nenhuma (nem sei que em ambiente você está trabalhando).

Comment: ótima resposta, muito obrigado! estou usando PHP no servidor, como preciso que o comprimento das *strings* seja igual no servidor e cliente talvez a solução seja utilizar `html_entity_decode()` e `.textContent / .innerText`

Answer (score 0):

apenas complementando, já que o conteúdo é obtido externamente, você pode requerer ele através de uma requisição ajax

```js
var external = document.getElementById("external");
var innerHTML = document.getElementById("innerHTML");
var responseText = document.getElementById("responseText");

var blob = new Blob(["<p>situa&ccedil;ão &gt; ativo</p>"], { type: "text/html" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {        
        external.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        innerHTML.value = external.innerHTML;
        responseText.value = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send("");
```

```css
div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}

input {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="external">
    
</div>
<div>
    <label for="innerHTML">innerHTML:</label>
    <input id="innerHTML" type="text" readonly />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="responseText">responseText:</label>
    <input id="responseText" type="text" readonly />
</div>
```